# Inline variables in Blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to include theme stylesheet into Blade template.
Unfortunately, code attached finishes with syntax error.
What’s wrong?

```
    <!-- Theme setup -->
    @php
        $theme = sprintf("css/themes/%s.css", config('app.dm.theme'));
        //error_log($theme);
    @endphp
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('@{{$theme}}') }}">
```

Comment: `{{ mix('@{{$theme}}') }}` - Are you sure you can have nested `{{ }}`? Can you post the complete error message and also point out on what row the error the error occurs?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix($theme) }}">` should do the trick. (Not sure what `@{{$theme}}` is supposed to do)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: error message is «syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')'»

Comment: @kerbholz: yes, it’s worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally.
1. Dot in config option allowed only after «app».
2. Working code looks like:

```
<!-- Theme setup -->
@php
    $theme = sprintf("css/themes/%s.css", config(‘app.dm-theme'));
@endphp
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix($theme) }}">
```